# How to cross validate undersampling?

Tags: logistic, cross-validation

In order to deal with an imbalanced data set I used undersampling to run a logit model.

The question might be simple but: How do I actually cross-validate undersampling?

Comment: clarification question: I'm used to thinking weighted sub-sampling.  Did you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis

Comment: Hey EngrStudent, yes this is exactly what I meant. Any ideas?

Comment: clarification question: so you had a pile with too many stones, and a pile with too few.  So you didn't use all the many, when you dealt with the few. (done that myself - forced by having the data I had, not the data I wished I had).  So you want to re-run the test a number of times and look at how the result changes.  It sounds a bit like looking at bootstrap resampling of a result - not exactly cross validation.  Is that correct?  When you say "undersample" what is your sample size?

Answer (score 2):

Two interpretations:

**1. How is it possible to cross validate your weights used in under sampling?**

(after your further comment, I know this is not your intent)

I don't believe you are going to have any luck answering this question. The reason for this is that cross validation is a method which is heavily based on the assumption that the distribution of data in the population is captured well in your sample, so leaving out some data from your fit and testing your model on that data should be a good proxy for how your model should fit on all the data you didn't sample.

On the other hand, under sampling is starting from the understanding that your sampled data is *not* representational of the true population, due to some outside information you have. Therefore, your data itself should contain no information about this bias.

**2. Your weights are trusted and you want to use cross validation to build your model**

In this case, there's not much you need to do: you are starting from the assumption that your new under-sampled data set is a representative sample from the true population (unlike your full dataset). As such, you can use your typical cross-validation approaches on your new under-sampled dataset.

If you really wanted to be extra fancy (and give yourself an extra headache), you could resample from your full data set for each left-out cross validated set. Similarly, I would think using probability weights would actually be better (and so your cross validation criteria would also be weighted), but perhaps that does not mesh well with your model of choice. But for large datasets, the gains of this compared with under-sampling may be minimal enough that it's just not worth the headache.

Comment: Thank your for the answer! I'm dealing with data where the majority class is over represented with the ratio 95 to 5 and is therefore not really suited for a logistic regression (due to small sample bias). As far as I understood random undersampling helps to increase the sensitivity and predictability of the model(?). Consequently I'd like to validate my findings and thought some sort of cross validation could help. Is there any other approach to validate the reliability of the undersampled model?

Comment: @Watermelon: ah, I see. I updated the answer.